# Cannot find method (class)(class)getRange((class),number) Error on Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have set up a Google form to submit an email with "Approve" or "Deny". Once either button is clicked in email, it should enter into a field in the spreadsheet. Instead I receive the following error:
Cannot find method (class)(class)getRange((class),number)

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AgiQ-iVBgD0HdDd3Xzh2aXJVRmRjQkI5dmhkd0pSMnc');
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRow();
var range = "A1:A"+lastRowNum;
var allResponseIDs = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRowNum, 1);
var cellValues = allResponseIDs.getValues();
var year = e.year;
var month = e.month;
var day = e["day-of-month"];
var today = month+'/'+day+'/'+year;

for(var i = 1; i <= lastRowNum; i++) {
 if(cellValues[i] === responseID) {
  var rowNumber = i;
}
}

var preApproved = sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 14, 1, 1);

if (!preApproved) {
  // Set the 1st level approval
  if (approvalOne === 'true') {
    sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 14, 1, 1).setValue(true);
  } else {
    sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 14, 1, 1).setValue(false);
  }
  sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 15, 1, 1).setValue(today);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There are many `getRange()` calls in your code. Can you pinpoint which of these is causing the problem. You can use the debug mode or if the code runs within a trigger, you can use the Logger functions to know which of these calls is complaining

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `getRange(rowNumber...` when `rowNumber` may not being defined.

If you did as Srik suggests, and ran this in the debugger, you'd probably find execution stopping at:

```
var preApproved = sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 14, 1, 1);
```

...and you'd see that `rowNumber` is undefined, because no match for `responseID` was found.

A couple of lines later, you're checking whether `preApproved` is "`true`ish". I don't know why you're doing that - maybe this is recognition that `responseID` might not be found, and an expectation that the result would be a null range for the resulting `getRange()` call. Or maybe you meant to get the value at that cell? (Let's assume that's the case - then you need to use `Range.getValue()`.)

Better would be to properly validate the result of the search. While doing that, you should be careful about mixing row/column numbering (which starts at 1) with array indices (that start at 0). Your `cellValues` are a two-dimensional array, populated by `Range.getValues()`.

```
var found = false;
var rowNumber = -1; // Would still throw an exception if used in getRange,
                    // but type is known, so better error message
for(var i = 0; i < lastRowNum; i++) {
  if(cellValues[i][0] === responseID) {
    found = true;
    var rowNumber = i+1;  // Adjust to 1-based indexing
    break;                // Done searching
  }
}

if (found) {

  var preApproved = sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 14, 1, 1).getValue();

  if (!preApproved) {
    // Set the 1st level approval
    if (approvalOne === 'true') {
      sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 14, 1, 1).setValue(true); 
    } else {
      sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 14, 1, 1).setValue(false);
    }
    sheet.getRange(rowNumber, 15, 1, 1).setValue(today);
    ...
  }
}
```